# Get least used id within another table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables

Account table

```
id INT, username TEXT, password TEXT, proxy_id INT, enabled BOOLEAN
```

Proxy table

```
id INT, proxy_ip TEXT, proxy_port INT
```

I would have a loop that goes through accounts one at a time. I want the least used proxy to be assigned to table.proxy_id.

for example if we have 2 proxies in the proxy table and 5 accounts in the Account table

```
1 10.0.0.1  4000
2 10.0.0.1  4001
```

Our accounts

```
1 david    password 2    enabled
2 mark     password 1    enabled
3 jessica  password 1    enabled
4 ashley   password NULL enabled
5 allan    password NULL enabled
6 james    password 2    disabled
```

My program will loop through all the enabled accounts, it will assign the least used proxy in the total enabled accounts to the account. In the example above David, mark and Jessica already have a proxy set. So the loop will go through Ashley and proxy with id 2 needs to be assigned to Ashley as it is the least used. For Allan proxy 1 or 2 can be assigned since it would be the least used in any case. James should be ignored since his account is not enabled.

I hope I was clear in my question. I think this would need to be done in two queries?

How would these queries look like?

Comment: Same proxy to all accounts? Could you improve your question by adding some accounts and the desired result?

Comment: no, the least used proxy. I will add accounts example

Comment: @McNets I have update the question

Comment: Please add the desired result.

Comment: @McNets I have written about the desired results in the paragraph bellow the accounts sample data

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE :** This solution is in `SQL SERVER`

You can do this using while loop.

Here is the query that will do

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1

WHILE @cnt > 0
BEGIN
   update TOP (1) account
  set account.proxy_id = (
      select top 1 proxy.id
      from proxy order by (
        select count(account.id)
        from account
        where account.proxy_id = proxy.id and account.enabled = 1
      )
  ) where account.proxy_id is null
   SET @cnt = (select count(id) from account where proxy_id is null and enabled = 1)
END;
```

In this query first we count all `account` for `proxy.id` in `proxy` table and select the `proxy.id` for lowest count.

Then we set that `id` to user who is `enabled` and does not have any `proxy_id`

**UPDATE :**

In **POSTGRESQL** you can achieve this by

```
DO $$DECLARE r int;
BEGIN
r=1;
    while r > 0 
    LOOP
        update account set proxy_id = (
            select proxy.id from proxy order by (
                select count(account.id)
                from account
                where account.proxy_id = proxy.id and account.enabled = '1'
            ) limit 1
        ) where id = (
                select id
                from account
                where proxy_id is null and enabled ='1'
                order by id limit 1
        );
        r = (select count(id) from account where proxy_id is null and enabled ='1');
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Comment: I will be using this within Java, I can break this into two queries so it would be more readable?

Comment: Also is your example for PostgreSQL?

Comment: @david Please check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> update accounts a
> set    proxy_id = (select max(id) from proxy)
> where  proxy_id is null
> and    enabled = true;
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from accounts order by id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username | password | proxy_id | enabled
> -: | :------- | :------- | -------: | :------
>  1 | david    | password |        2 | t      
>  2 | mark     | password |        1 | t      
>  3 | jessica  | password |        1 | t      
>  4 | ashley   | password |        2 | t      
>  5 | allan    | password |        2 | t      
>  6 | james    | password |        2 | f
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7221c08ad8e80eed746dbf0c676f6dae)*

Comment: This takes the last proxy in the account table. Not the least used